# Can't read Datetime from Excel sheet using Azure Logic Apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Good day! I am trying to pull data from excel sheet and will ingest to SQL database using Azure Logic Apps but it was not ingesting any data due to DateTime format, even I already have parseDateTime in my workflow design. Can you please help me on this matter? Thank you

[image]

Comment: Can you post the error as text (I can't see pictures)

Comment: Hello, there's no error at all. It was not just ingesting since the design can't read the DateTime from the excel sheet. Thank you

Comment: So show us what the data looks like, that’s the trick to having things resolved.

Comment: The answer posted by Rickwikbojja helps me to resolve my concern. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and below are the expected results:

To send datetime to SQL from excel through Logic apps use below method:

**`Firstly store Datetime as text in this format:`**

[image]

**`To change to text:`**

[image]

**`Then:`**

[image]

**`Then add input:`**

```
DateTime
9-1-2023  0:00
9-2-2023  8:00
9-3-2023  10:00
```

**`Sql table:`**

[image]

**`Design:`**

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]

[image]

**`Checking if values got inserted:`**

[image]

This is a trick to send datetime to sql from logic app.